# Check if a space in an Array of records is free

Tags: arrays, delphi, save, records

I'm programming a database in Delphi for my coursework and I have encountered an issue.

```
  UserRecord = record
                  Forename : string[20];
                  Surname  : string[20];
                  Username : string[20];
                  Password : string[20];
                  gender   : boolean;
                end;

var
  User : UserRecord;
  NewUserForm: TNewUserForm;
  UserFile : file of UserRecord;
  UserArray : array[1..20] of UserRecord;
```

this is cut down version of my code, I would like to be able to save the record 'UserRecord' into the Array UserArray, which is a simple thing to do, however if there is already one 'user' in the first entry point of my array, it will override it. I need to find a way to check through the array to find an empty point in the array, so I can save it there instead of constantly overriding the first entry point.

Comment: Don't use fixed length arrays. Use dynamic arrays of `TList<UserRecord>`. Don't use short strings. Use `string`. Also, gender is not a `Boolean`!!!

Comment: When you use `file of record`, you should declare your record as `packed`, otherwise you will be saving padding junk.

Comment: Oh, and stop using file of record also!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan unless there would be stock `TFileStream<T>` it might sometimes be a rather nice concept.  Though for just 20 elements i'd prefer `blockread` them all. OTOH that might be the courses who only taught then old Wirth-Pascal style of things.

Comment: Don't listed to David, otherwise you gonna fail your coursework :-P

Comment: You can simply remember e.g. the last used index in that array. Whenever you write a record, you check if it's below array length and if so, then you increase that value and write the record on that position in the array.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Would be a lame course that failed you for writing good code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, there is nothing good in rewriting code for no benefit.

Comment: @Free True. But that's not what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

```
function AddUserRecord(ARecord: UserRecord; var AUserArray: array of UserRecord): integer;
var
  EmptyRecord: UserRecord;
  I: Integer;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@EmptyRecord, SizeOf(UserRecord));
  Result := -1;
  for I := Low(AUserArray) to High(AUserArray) do
    //Compare with an empty record
    if CompareMem(@EmptyRecord, @AUserArray[I], SizeOf(UserRecord)) then
    begin
      AUserArray[I] := ARecord;
      Result := I; 
      Exit;
    end;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  UserArray : array[1..20] of UserRecord;
  User : UserRecord;
begin
  //initialize record array
  ZeroMemory(@UserArray, SizeOf(UserArray));

  //Your logic to fill the record
  //ZeroMemory(@User, SizeOf(UserRecord));
  //User.Username := 'X';

  AddUserRecord(User, UserArray);

end;
```

Comment: implicit assuming instead of explicit value... might one day bite.  Also, if you use `Exit(value)` then you must be using a rather modern Delphi and then you probably can compare records rather than falling back to `CompareMemory`

Comment: and Yes again, assuming is not the best way and your answer is robust, bug he say that is from "coursework" so I guess he can't change the record. So yes, yours is better :) but mine works this case

Comment: With outdated courseworks, it is sometimes a dumb lottery, what one can change and what he can not.

Comment: @Arioch'The comparing records requires operator overloading

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether the row was filled or is null, the best way s to add an explicit flag, that you would use to mark real rows from deleted ones, like in DBF files. The never-filled cells might be considered the same as deleted, unless you don't want to change the length of the array on the run.

```
type UserRecord = record
  Forename : string[20];
  Surname  : string[20];
  Username : string[20];
  Password : string[20];
  gender   : boolean;
  FreeSpot : Boolean;
end;
```

After this addition you would have to initialize the variables, so they would not contain wrong data or even garbage. You would have to run a loop through your storage buffer, and mark they all unused like

```
for I := Low( UserArray ) to High( UserArray ) do
    deleteRecord( I ); // initialize buffer so we can start saving data

procedure deleteRecord(const I: integer);
begin
    UserArray[ I ].FreeSpot := true;
end;
```

After that you can make a data row saving routine like that:

```
// returns the array index where the data was stored, or -1 if did not saved
function storeRecord(const data: UserRecord ): integer;
begin
  for Result := Low( UserArray ) to High( UserArray ) do
      if UserArray[ Result ].FreeSpot then 
      begin
        UserArray[ Result ] := data;
        UserArray[ Result ].FreeSpot := false;
        Exit();  
      end;

  Result := -1; // out of the loop - found no free cell to take
end;
```

In case you cannot add fields to the records you can try

```
type UserRecord = record
  Forename : string[20];
  Surname  : string[20];
  Username : string[20];
  Password : string[20];
  gender   : boolean;
end;
UserRecordSlot = record
  Data : UserRecord;
  FreeSpot : Boolean;
end;

UserArray : array of UserRecordSlot;

// returns the array index where the data was stored, or -1 if did not saved
function storeRecord(const data: UserRecord ): integer;
begin
  for Result := Low( UserArray ) to High( UserArray ) do
      if UserArray[ Result ].FreeSpot then 
      begin
        UserArray[ Result ].Data := data;
        UserArray[ Result ].FreeSpot := false;
        Exit();  
      end;

  Result := -1; // out of the loop - found no free cell to take
end;
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that you must initialize all the `FreeSpot` members to True before you store the first record.

Comment: @TLama okay. But I really don't want to write all the code :-) That was just the seed for the homework to be taken and continued by the topic starter

Comment: Also, `FreeSpot` field might be less meaningful on disk than in memory.

Comment: @FreeConsulting i thought about that, and i decided that on disk it has much more sense than in memory: disk files can be read by other programs, today and in ten years into the future. So having the clear mark if there is data in the row or there is not is quite important. And users of DBF files format probably think the same :-)